# Se duplica el evento al editar onclick desde el inspector de elementos del navegador

Tags: javascript, html, consola

Tengo un código simple en `html`, un `button`.

```
<button onclick="data('123456')">btnClick</button>
```

Si abro el index en Google Chrome o Edge ocurre el siguiente problema:

Al cambiar el parámetro desde el inspector elementos por ejemplo **54321** y al hacer click, me manda por consola el dato modificado y sin modificar, o sea dos datos y no solo el modificado. Es decir tanto `123456` como `54321`

Demo:

```js
function data(number) {
  console.log(number)
}
```

```html
 <button onclick="data('123456')">btnClick</button>
```

Lo anterior es solo un ejemplo reproducible (mcve), mi intención real es hacer una validación, por ejemplo que el parámetro sea un **id** encriptado el cual después lo desencripto para luego ver si existe en una base de datos, si está correcto me retornaría un `modal` y si no está correcto el **id** desencriptado me retornaría un `alert` con error. Pero como me está enviado dos datos, el modificado y no modificado, me mandaría tanto el `modal` como el `alert`

Este error solo pasa en el navegador Edge y Google Chrome, mas no en Mozilla

Comment: No olvides describir brevemente en el título el problema en cuestión.

Comment: Hola Carlos, si estoy entendiendo bien, estás editando "en caliente" tu html, y los distintos browsers responden de distinta forma a los cambios, no lo veo como un problema de tu código, sino más bien como limitaciones de las herramientas de depuración de algunos browsers.

Comment: Dices que en chrome y edge se imprime 2 veces el log? A mi no me pasa

Comment: Me atrevo a decir que esta parte de tu lógica no es correcta: _"Pero como me está enviado dos datos, el modificado y no modificado, me mandaría tanto el modal como el alert"_. Si usas `ajax` o `fetch` para enviar el **id** como parámetro, **_este no estaría "quemado" en el código al crear el DOM y mucho menos tendrías por qué modificarlo en el inspector de código ya que sería una vulnerabilidad_**. Luego, haces la validación en `php` y retornas una única respuesta a `JavaScript`, **no hay razón para que se entreguen los dos elementos al DOM**.

Comment: @Pipe si modificas el parámetro del botón en el inspector de código, se puede observar el comportamiento que indica el OP. Por ejemplo, `<button onclick="data('987654')">btnClick</button>`, en la consola se imprimen tanto el valor quemado **123456** como el modificado **987654**.

Comment: Tu codigo no es suficiente como para decir algo certero, ahi solo pones un log, no es como si nosotros pudiesemos adivinar exactamente como envias los datos, quizas el problema este en otro lado, porque tu dices que "envias datos", pero pareciera que solo estas probando cosas en consola.

Answer (score 0):

Al editar el evento e en el inspector, el navegador agrega otros `eventListener` al elemento. Es el equivalente a hacer

```
button.addEventListener("click", a=> data("1234"));
button.addEventListener("click", a=> data("otracosa")); //este lo agrega el navegador cuando lo editas.
```

**¿Tiene sentido?**

Para mí no, porque el evento se está editando a través de su propiedad `onclick`, no a través de `addEventListener`. Pero que sabe un simple mortal de la magia negra detrás de los navegadores.

Así está el evento cuando se inicia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al hacer un cambio con el inspector:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora si te fijas en la última imagen hay un botón "quitar", donde puedes remover el evento antiguo para realizar tus pruebas.